# How to swipe between multiple uiview

Tags: ios, memory-management, uiview, swipe

What is the best solution to swipe multiple UIviews ?
In my app, I have multiple views (40 views) and I want to swipe between.
With UIScrollView, I can use pagingEnabled but I'm afraid that memory exploses !
What is the trick to keep low memory ?

Thanks

Comment: The mechanism is like `UITableView`, you can reuse the UIViews just like `UITableView` reuse `UITableViewCell`

Comment: Are you loading your views lazily ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the type of look/feel you're going for you might want to take a look at:

1. `UICollectionView` with a custom layout (http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12)
2. `UIPageViewController` if each page is more complex (http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-tutorial-intro/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `UICollectionView` [docs here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html). `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` with `UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal` scrolling direction and full screen cell size will do the job. Don't use `UITableView` for horizontal paging.